# Can't figure out why React Hook is invalid

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to use useContext hook in a React Native page I have, I'm using this hook in other components as well and they work just fine, but this one won't - can't figure out why.
This is my component:

```
const GoalCard = (goal: IGoal) => {   
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext); <-- error is here

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.card, {height: cardHeight, backgroundColor: "#ff5e"}]}>
      <View>
         .....
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
```

I'm using this component inside a FlatList which is in a separate file.

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[styles.pageContainer, {backgroundColor: theme.background}]}>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{padding: 8}}
        data={goals}
        renderItem={({index}) => GoalCard(goals[index])}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

I get the error: `Invalid hook call`, but it does not seem like something is wrong here.
Saw few questions about this, but none worked, also, nothing seems wrong according to the `Rules of Hooks` page. Why this error happens here?

EDIT:
this is my ThemeProvider:

```
function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  const [dark, setDark] = React.useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setDark(!dark); 
  }

  const theme = dark ? themes.dark : themes.light;

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, dark, toggle}}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And this is my App.tsx:

```
 <ThemeProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
             .....
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: I can't see where you call `createContext`...

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Sorry, I forgot to add it, but I have a theme.js file where I use createContext.

Comment: Perfect and then you also use `<ThemeContext.Provider>...</ThemeContext.Provider>` somewhere, correct?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Yes, thank you. I already have that part. I guess I should have added it earlier, but I added it now to my original post so it would be more clear.

Comment: i can't see any error in your code, try add more code.